How to add options to control streaming settings (e.g., resolution and FPS)
I am working on a project that involves both object detection and video recording. I want to control the resolution and frame rate of the ImageStream input to tflite images to improve performance. Additionally, the camera screen display requires high resolution, and the frame rate and resolution for recording and analysis need to be set separately. Currently, when using Flutter camera to set ResolutionReset, the preview screen may become blurry. Are there any good solutions?
 cameraController = CameraController(
      firstCamera,
      ResolutionPreset.high,
      enableAudio: false,
    );

Future<void> startImageStreamAnalysis() async {
    await cameraController?.startImageStream((CameraImage img) {
      analysis(img);
    });
  }
  Future<void> analysis(CameraImage img) async {
    if (!isDetecting) {
      isDetecting = true;
      await Tflite.detectObjectOnFrame(
        bytesList: img.planes.map((plane) {
          return plane.bytes;
        }).toList(),
        model: "YOLO",
        imageHeight: img.height,
        imageWidth: img.width,
        imageMean: 0,
        imageStd: 255.0,
        numResultsPerClass: 1,`your text`
        threshold: 0.2,
      ).then((recognitions) {
        widget.setRecognitions(recognitions!, img.height, img.width);
        isDetecting = false;
      });
    }
  }

